# How do I defeat Swans as a melee-oriented character?

Tags: fallout-4

Finding it really hard to get in on Swans without eating a chunk of huge HP while playing as a melee character.

For reference I'm playing a low charisma, low intelligence, high strength, high endurance character.  I'm getting quite frustrated as frequently dying to Swans is annoying, and running away isn't a mantra I'm fond of, so what's the best way to defeat Swans as a melee-oriented character?

Comment: 4 minutes after writing a [tag:fallout-4] question and not a single downvote yet. There's got to be an achievement for this!

Comment: While technically wrong for this question, @WalterBohun's question does point in a slightly non-useless direction. How would you feel about giving Fat Man or Big Boy to your companion?

Comment: If only you had the Furious Power Fist....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact same problem too. I just came back later when I had a better weapon / more perks (Rooted is amazing as a melee user - 25% less damage taken when standing still I believe).

Otherwise, buff up on chems and try to get your companion to kite him around.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -11):

Honestly, I just went at him with a Fat Man. IF you keep your distance with a Hazmat Suit, you'll be fine.

Comment: A **melee**-oriented character would not use a Fat Man

Comment: Most players end up with them anyways

Comment: @WalterBohun That's not the point. The OP wants to know how to beat him when their character is a melee-only combatant. This precludes Fat Man.